# A Perfect Diamond of Numbers

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, optimization

A *diamond* of numbers is an arrangement of circles in the shape of a trapezoid (see figure) in which the number in any circle above its central (longest) row is the sum of the two numbers in the circles that it lies on, while the number in any circle below the central row is the (absolute) difference of the two numbers in the circles that lie on it. The diamond is *perfect* if all the numbers used are different positive integers.

What is the least number that can occupy the top circle of a perfect diamond whose central row consists of four circles?

What if the central row consists of 5 or 6 circles?

[image]

Comment: You should consider submitting this sequence (of which the puzzle's answers are the 4th, 5th, and 6th terms) to oeis.org !

Comment: @GregMartin I shall do so, thanks Greg!

Comment: I added terms from 1 to 7 to my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Four circles:

> 37

> ```
>      37
>    14  23
>  10   4  19
> 9   1   3  16
>   8   2  13
>     6  11
>       5
> ```

Five circles:

> 103

> ```
>         103
>       49   54
>     32   17  37
>   22  10    7  30
> 18   4    6   1  29
>   14   2    5  28
>     12    3  23
>        9   20
>          11
> ```

Six circles:

> 267

> ```
>            267
>         105   162
>       68    37   125
>     54   14    23   102
>   44  10     4    19   83
> 35   9    1     3    16  67
>   26   8     2    13   51
>     18    6    11    38
>       12     5    27
>           7    22
>             15
> ```

I used mixed integer linear programming to find these optimal solutions, and the first several optimal values are:

> 1, 4, 13, 37, 103, 267, 645

Comment: If these are _proven optimal_ then it would be good to say so and say how. (Though I think I can already guess how.)

Comment: Are you able to post more of these here or somewhere else? I have a partial answer that tries to solve this analytically but I need more data

Comment: Do you want the actual solutions or just the number in the top circle?

Answer (score 6):

Best I've found so far is

> ```
>        40
>      13  27
>     9   4  23
>   8   1   3  20
>     7   2  17
>       5  15
>        10
> ```

but I haven't exhausted alternatives just yet

Comment: Thanks, hexomino.  Apparently one of those days...^_^b

Comment: No problem, good answer.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be:

> 68?
>
> ```
>        68
>      17  51
>     4  13  38
>   1   3  10  28
>     2   7  18
>       5  11
>         6
> ```

If so,

> I just naively proceeded with the assumption that I should start with the smallest numbers possible in the middle row; I adjusted these up whenever I encountered a conflict downstream. (e.g. The second circle in the middle row couldn't be 2, because the difference between 1 and 2 would be 1, a number already used.)